# forEachResult() method is limited to 4000 rows in the result set returned

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, netsuite

Good day! our NetSuite suitelet script is limited to 4000 rows in the result set returned, any idea on how do we script to be able to more than 4000 rows using the forEachResult() method?

```
var resultNumber=0;
                studentRecordsObj.run().each(function(result){
                  log.debug("processing row #", ++resultNumber);
                    sponsorshipNumberField.addSelectOption({
                        value: result.id,
                        text: result.getValue({name: 'custrecord12'}) + ' ' + result.getValue({name: 'custrecord_name'}),
                    })
                    return true;
                })
```

trying to resolve using the other ideas.  thank you

Comment: Are you sure that the limitation on the amount of rows returned is due to your code or something on NetSuite's end?

Comment: yes sir, i already raise these issues to NetSuite and they checked the entire system, the error message we received is not due to defect as they said. they are advising as to modify our code.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Instead of fetching records and iterating over them and adding option all at once, try splitting your code. So maybe start first with just getting the records then once you have your records, add another portions that  adds the options.

Comment: the message appears:  "SSS_SEARCH_FOR_EACH_LIMIT_EXCEEDED",  i think we need to revise the criteria and callback logic so that no more than 4000 returned.

Answer (score 2):

### Answer

`ResultSet.each(callback)` has a limitation of 4,000 results, as documented in [this SuiteAnswers article](https://suiteanswers.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/43899):

> Use a developer-defined function to invoke on each row in the search results, up to 4000 results at a time.

To overcome this limitation you can:

1. Use `Search.run().getRange()` to iterate the full result set by range, and then iterate the results contained in each range.
2. Use `Search.runPaged()`, `fetch` the data for each page and iterate the results.  Example:

   ```
       var searchObj = searchObjSearch.runPaged({
           pageSize:1000
       });
       searchObj.pageRanges.forEach(function (pageRange) {
           searchObj.fetch({
               index:pageRange.index
           })
           .data.forEach(function (result) {
               //Process each search result here
           });
               csv.push(row);
               row = {};
           });
       });
   ```

### Unsolicited Extra Advice

Processing thousands of results in a Suitelet may result in slow execution and hitting governance limits.  Also, as it appears you are adding the results to a select field, users may find it unwieldy to select from so many options.

Consider whether you can reduce the number of results by adding a filter to the saved search or incorporating a dynamic filter within the Suitelet page (by this I mean a field that the user can select or enter a value, and a `fieldChanged()` event in an attached client script which then reloads the Suitelet using that field's value in an additional filter).